# How to to fetch data from SQLite db in a separate thread and use it in the main thread callback?

Tags: java, multithreading, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have a method in my `Fragment` that fetches values from a local database and puts this data in `RecyclerView`. The data fetching lasts long that retards UI, so I decide to put it in a separate thread. I want the separate thread to return a method call from my main thread.

What are the best practices to do this?

## Edit

I want to elaborate on my question, because the feedback I receive is not solving my problem. I will keep my original question untouched and edit the code.

I want to call in my `Fragment` a method that would fetch from an `SQLite` database some data in a separate thread and, subsequently, call a callback in the main thread to make use of the fetched data to update the UI. The data will be used in `ReciclerView`. The code equivalent, as I imagine it, should look like this:

```
private Context context;
private List<T> mData;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();

    //-----------------Thread starts here.-------------------------
    List<T> threadData = getData();

    private List<T> getData(){
        List<T> returnList;
        ...Go in SQLite database (Context required) to populate returnList...
        return returnList;
    }
    //-------Thread ends here and calls threadOnFinish() callback in the  main thread--------
}

@Overwrite
private void threadOnFinish(List<T> threadData,...){
    useData(threadData);
}

private void useData(List<T> newData){
    mData = newData;
    ...Use data and update UI...
}
```

Please, help

Comment: I would recommend change 'data' type from list to something like blocking queue, the getData would then keep adding data to that queue and main thread would be blocked on it till the queue has the data.

Comment: you should create a class that will implement interface *Runnable* or *Callable*(void or T return type)after it you should create an instance of class Thread and transfer to him you *Runnable* or *Callable* implementation. Put your code for the second thread in the method's "run" implementation.

Comment: I have updated my question with the abstract code

Answer (score 0):

Create class thats implements Runnable

```
private class DataClass implements Runnable {

    private volatile List<T> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...Background task...
        data = listFromDatabase;
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
public List<T> getData() throws InterruptedException {
    DataClass dataClass = new DataClass();
    Thread thread = new Thread(dataClass);
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
    return dataClass.getData();
}
```

This is gonna wait value to be fetched and then return it's value.

Comment: You even don't need to use volatile for the data field because: 1. it is guarantee visibility of the reference the list (of an instance of the list prepared in run()), but not visibility of its elements (you should use right sequence to have HB, for example, build/fill-in a local list completely and only after that make the volatile write to the list field) 2. .join() makes a HB edge itself (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

Comment: I have updated my question with the abstract code. Does your solution still hold?

Comment: Yes, "Go to SQL" would then be in DataClass's run(), you have all the code you need